# .NET Core - registering services, how to register separate version of a service

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-core

I have an interface `IService` and two implementations `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`.

For most of the time I want to use implementation `A`, but I also have another service that wants implementation `B`. Is there a way of doing just that? It should look something like this:

```
services.AddScoped<IService, ServiceA>();

services.AddScoped<ISomethingElse, SomethingElse>();
services.WhenResolving<ISomethingElse>.AddScoped<IService, ServiceB>();
```

Comment: what is the other case? yes It is quite possible

Comment: Have a look at this [option](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/asp-net-core-dependency-injection-registering-multiple-implementations-interface) and let me know if that helps?

Comment: @Morema interesting read, but doesn't really help :)

Comment: I want a particular instance, one in one case and another in another case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to mention two versions of doing this.

First, Let say that you have configuration parameter and according to your configuration parameter you decide which service will be resolved by your Interface

then

```
services.AddScoped<ISomethingElseService, SomethingService>();

if (Configuration["MyServiceParam"] == "X")
    services.AddScoped<ISomethingService, SomethingElseService>();
```

the other option is

```
services.AddScoped<ISomethingService>(s => {
   var MyServiceA = s.GetService<MyServiceA>();
   if (MyServiceA is null)
      return new SomethingElseService();
   else
      return new SomethingService(MyServiceA);
});
```

Comment: Not ideal, but I managed to adapt your second example for our needs